# What does bash -s do?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I'm new to bash and trying to understand what the script below is doing, i know `-e` is exit but i'm not sure what `-se` or what the `$delimiter` is for?

```
$delimiter = 'EOF-MY-APP';

$process = new SSH(
    "ssh $target 'bash -se' << \\$delimiter".PHP_EOL
        .'set -e'.PHP_EOL
        .$command.PHP_EOL
        .$delimiter
);
```

Comment: `-s` reads commands from standard input.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash (source: ten second google search)

Comment: ^^ So, is `-s` redundant? Can anyone provide an example, where `-s` is required?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @RyanBemrose It's 2020 and the first result when Googling "bash -s" is this page :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ```
> -s   If  the -s option is present, or if no arguments remain after
>      option processing, then commands are read from the standard
>      input.  This option allows the positional parameters to be
>      set when invoking an interactive shell.
> ```

From [`help set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> ```
>  -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
> ```

So, this tells bash to read the script to execute from Standard Input, and to exit immediately if any command in the script (from stdin) fails.

The delimiter is used to mark the start and end of the script. This is called a [Here Document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) or a heredoc.

Comment: The cited part looks incomplete :(

Comment: In this case the `-s` option is redundant, since there are no arguments to the script.

Comment: @sjsam That came from running the `man`/`help` commands on my Mac.

Answer (score 23):

The `-s` options is usually used along with the `curl $script_url | bash` pattern. For example,

```
curl -L https://chef.io/chef/install.sh | sudo bash -s -- -P chefdk
```

`-s` makes bash read commands (the "install.sh" code as downloaded by "curl") from stdin, and accept positional parameters nonetheless.

`--` lets bash treat everything which follows as positional parameters instead of  options.

bash will set the variables `$1` and `$2` of the "install.sh" code to `-P` and to `chefdk`, respectively.

Reference: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28671064/what-is-the-role-of-bash-s.html

Comment: Note: This might not work as expected if the script consists of script header and binary data.